# Newly Build Computer Not Running POST

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, troubleshooting, computer-building, post

I build a computer using entirely new parts (except for the video card with I used in my old computer for about a month before deciding to upgrade everything). When I turn it on the fans run and some lights turn on, but the screen is completely black and there is no beeping. I've never even gotten to BIOS. From what I could tell, this means that POST is not running. I took out the CPU and looked at the pins, but they all seemed straight to me. As far as I can tell, the PSU is hooked up correctly. The guides I have found say that the next step is to start replacing parts one by one until the situation changes. However, I don't have a bunch of compatible parts lying around that I can do that with. What should I do next?

**Parts List**

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600

Motherboard: MSI MAG B550 Tomahawk

Video Card: MSI GeForce GT 1030

SSD: Samsung 970 Evo Pluss 500GB

RAM: Crucial Ballistix 8GB (two installed)

Comment: Check the PSU that each output is putting out the correct voltage within 3%. That is all you can do without replacement parts to test.

Comment: Since there are no beeps, it might be working properly.  Do you have a spare graphics card to test with?

Comment: Is your motherboard actually compatible with this CPU? When I bought my Ryzen 5 2600X, the motherboard was not compatible and required a BIOS update. All Ryzen CPU's will have the same issue where a BIOS update will flash it so that a certain subset of processors will work, and older processors will eventually be removed to free up space, but for newer cpu's you do need to have a certain bios update already. In my case I did need to install an older CPU to flash it first.

Comment: See also: https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/MAG-B550-TOMAHAWK#support-cpu, looks like this one is supported out of the box.